# Is there an app to convert a video to HTML / JS / JSON?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, video, html, javascript

Apple's site does some neat tricks on their pages to display videos encoded as a JPG file and then decoded and rendered in a canvas element (see http://www.tuaw.com/2012/10/16/how-apples-iphone-5-website-works/).

Is there an app that will take a video and convert it into that?

I remember seeing something like that announced, but can't find any reference or link on my notes.

Answer (score 2):

I found one such app: [Phosphor](http://www.divergentmedia.com/phosphor)

It does what I required.

Comment: Also spelled **Phosphor**